# WEB URL for CVS

Tags: cvs

I have a weburl from which I can browse a cvs repository, also I can download files when I click on a file and select download.

I want to get all the files to be checked out to folder on the local machine, how do I do this?

URL is http://server.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/?cvsroot=LAILA

I have tried with WINCVS but it did not work out, is there any way I can use some HTTP based CVS client & get all the source files

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cvs does not provide web-based access to the repository. There is web-based software that provides you with a limited view of the repository. Assuming the example url you gave matches the server you are connecting to, it is using [cvsweb](http://www.freebsd.org/projects/cvsweb.html).

If you want to check out all of the code using a cvs client (and perhaps commit changes) you will have to see if the website has any information on how to access the cvs repository. If not, you may need to contact the site administrator for such information.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a slightly different URL for the cvs server, it should be available on your site somewhere.